# How to implement a function that can be called with new keyword in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to implement a factory function in TypeScript, which takes a object and append missing fields with the corresponding one in the default object.

I think it makes sense to only allow the function to be called with `new` keyword as it returns a new object every time.

Here are my code.

```
type User = {
  new <T>(suppliedValue: Partial<T>, defaultValue: T): T;
};

type Admin = {
  username: string;
  permission: ('write' | 'read')[];
}

export const User: User = (<T>(suppliedValue: Partial<T>, defaultValue: T) => {
  return Object.assign({}, suppliedValue, defaultValue);
}) as any as User;

const defaultAdmin: Admin = { username: 'Default Username', permission: [] }

const anAdminInstance: Admin = new User<Admin>({ username: 'Foo' }, defaultAdmin);
```

Is it possible write `User` function without type assertions?

Comment: Typescript explicitly doesn't support writing constructor functions - you are supposed to write classes instead. These can be compiled to constructor functions if necessary, by setting the appropriate output language level.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not be easier with a plain old class?

```
export class User {
    _user: User = {
        // ... default values here
    }

    constructor ( userValues?: Partial<User> ) {
        this._user = {
            ...this._user,
            ...userValues
        };
    }

    getUser(): User {
        return _user;
    }
}
```

then

```
const defaultAdmin: Admin = {
    username: 'Default Username',
    permission: []
}
const fooAdmin: Admin = {
    ...defaultAdmin,
    userName: 'Foo'
}
const anAdminInstance: User = new User( fooAdmin );
```